# Django + Bootstrap modal form still shows Djangos default errors, not bootstrapped errors?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-forms

I am struggling with displaying bootstraps form errors in a popup form modal. When I submit the form, with some missing required fields, I am still getting Django's built in basic form error messages, or even if a field requires a decimal, I enter text, I get an error but it's still django's built in basic validation error. I am using crispy-forms and bootstrap to try to display the errors in a nicer way on the page.

This is the way errors are being displayed now....

[image]

I have a simple form here...

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<form role="form" method="post" name="employee-add" id="employee-add"  action="{% url 'employee_add' company_id %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="companyID" name="comp" value="{{ company_id }}">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-inner defult-inner">
    {% for field in employee_form %}
          <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
              <span class="error-msg">{{ error }}</span>s
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
    {% endfor %}
      <div class="footer-button employee-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="save">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The modal form is populated with an AJAX `GET` request.

```
$(function () {
    // GET request to grab employee form.

    $(".js-create").click(function () {
    let employee_id = $("input[name='employee_id']").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: `/company/employee/${employee_id}/`,
      type: 'get',
      data: {'employee_id': employee_id},
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-employee").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-employee .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
      }
    });
    });
});
```

Django view...

```
@csrf_protect
def employee_create(request, company_id):

    template_name = 'business/employee-create.html'
    data = dict()
    company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        employee_form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if employee_form.is_valid():
            logger.debug('Valid')
            emp = employee_form.save(commit=False)
            emp.company = venue
            emp.user = request.user
            emp.save()
            return redirect('comp_detail', company_id=company_id)
        else:
            logger.debug('Error')

    else:
        employee_form = EmployeeForm()
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string(
            template_name,
            {'employee_form': employee_form, 'company_id': company.id},
            request=request,
        )
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I feel as though its something here..

```
{% for field in employee_form %}
          <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
            {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <span class="error-msg">{{ error }}</span>s
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Because, the `has-error` class never shows up when I inspect the page. Then if I remove the `{% if field.errors %}`line and just add the `has-error` class, the form loads with the nice red bootstrap form border. So I know bootstrap is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable validation in the browser. Just add `novalidate` to your form.

```
<form novalidate="novalidate">...</form>
```

Comment: hmm what that did  just sent me to a page displaying the JSON in the else statement.....  `{'form_is_valid: False}`

Answer (score 0):

try to use this  `{% for error in  form.non_field_errors %}`. Hope it will solve your problems.